# Error message when setting up code repo in ADF

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I come across an error message when I set up code repository in Azure Data Factory:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2Nbv.png)

I have a bunch of repos in this Azure DevOps account. But I cannot choose any of them.

I confirm that the Azure DevOps account has already connected to my organization Active Directory.

Comment: Hi @Kylie Fu, Have you got a chance to check the answer below? If adding your account as a PCA in Azure DevOps, will the expected organization be listed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you have the needed permissions on Azure devops to make the connect.

According to MS documentation: You must be a member of the Project Collection Administrators group or the organization Owner to make the connection.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/connect-organization-to-azure-ad?view=azure-devops](https://You%20must%20be%20a%20member%20of%20the%20Project%20Collection%20Administrators%20group%20or%20the%20organization%20Owner%20to%20make%20the%20connection.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Yes you are right. I had two accounts in Azure DevOps, one is organization owner and the other is contributor of a project. I didn't notice this.